# Project Euler # 5; this solution works - but why?

Tags: c++, algorithm

The project Euler problem 5 is stated as : "2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"
Here's the c++ code for the function I'm using.

```
    long long unsigned int rangeLCM(int n)
    {
         long long unsigned int ans=1;
         for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
            if(ans%i!=0)
            {
              if(i%(ans%i)==0)ans*=(i/(ans%i));
              else ans*=i;
            }
         } 
         return ans;
    }
```

The code works well for the example stated in the problem and the problem itself{`rangeLCM(10)=2520` and `rangeLCM(20)=232792560`}, but I think it's not perfect and is missing out on some edge cases.

Instead of actually calculating the `LCM(ans,i)`, I have checked that the bigger of the two(always `ans`) is divisible by `i`. If not, then `ans` is multiplied by a number equal to `i/(ans%i)` or `i` depending on whether `i` is divisible by `(ans%i)` or not.

This is based on the following facts:

```
LCM(8,12)=24=12*(8/(12%8));

LCM(9,30)=90=30*(9/(30%9)

LCM(7,13)=91=13*7
```

However, it fails for the following types of cases:`LCM(8,14)=56 != 8*14`

Yet, the code for rangeLCM gives the right output for all inputs I have tried yet. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic does not work

```
          if(i%(ans%i)==0)ans*=(i/(ans%i));
          else ans*=i;
```

For example, if `ans = 10` and `i = 14`, so, the lcm should be 70, but in your code, it is 140.

The reason is, between `ans` and `i` , there are common divisors, but your code cannot detect that.

For experiment, I have written a small piece of code to check using Java.

```
class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ans = 1;
        for (long i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
            if (ans % i != 0) {

                long before = (ans*i/gcd(ans,i));
                if (i % (ans % i) == 0){
                    ans *= (i / (ans % i));
                }else{
                    ans *= i;
                }
                System.out.println(ans + " " + before + " " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static long gcd(long a, long b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

Output

```
2 2 2
6 6 3
12 12 4
60 60 5
420 420 7
840 840 8
2520 2520 9
27720 27720 11
360360 360360 13
720720 720720 16
12252240 12252240 17
232792560 232792560 19
5354228880 5354228880 23
26771144400 26771144400 25
722820898800 80313433200 27
20961806065200 20961806065200 29
649815988021200 649815988021200 31
1299631976042400 1299631976042400 32
48086383113568800 48086383113568800 37
```

When i = 27, there is different between the correct answer and `ans`

The formula for lcm(a,b) is

```
lcm(a,b) = a*b/gcd(a,b)
```

With gcd is [Greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) between two number a and b

Comment: That is true, but if i is 14, then ans will not be 10. I understand this solution won't work for a simple 2 number LCM, but will it for what it has been made - finding the LCM of a range? Because it seems to be running fine for ranges.

Comment: @glear14195 there is a wrong case for range from 1 to 27. This is the smallest range that this is failed :)

Comment: Could you please post the correct output for the range 1 to 27?

Comment: @glear14195 updated my answer. So, your function will give wrong answer from 27 onward.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It gives the wrong answer for 27 and the right answer for 29,31,32...??

Comment: @glear14195 no, as it is wrong from 27, so it affects the result from 27 onward.

Comment: But your code shows that the answers match for 29,31,32...?

Comment: @glear14195 `long before = (ans*i/gcd(ans,i));`,  `before` is calculated based on previous `ans`. As the last `ans` is wrong, so all the next values are wrong too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80748/discussion-between-glear14195-and-pham-trung).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a lot of cases you have to implement the Euclidean algorithm at

```
if(i%(ans%i)==0)ans*=(i/(ans%i));
```

Comment: I understand that, but this piece of code works. My question is why? And if not that then please point out an example where it doesn't work.